# Why Facebook is able to launch my app through app invitation in iOS 9 beta 3 (openURL: also works)?

Tags: ios, ios9

So Apple has changed how **openURL:** and **canOpenURL:** work in iOS 9, an app has to register specific URL schemes they would like to open in their whitelists, which can only be updated by submitting an update to iTunes. 
Otherwise, these two methods will always return *FALSE* (i.e. not able to open that app).

However, I sent an app invitation through Facebook, and I was able to open my app on my device through clicking the "Open" button in Facebook's app (my device for testing is currently iOS 9 beta 3). How is this possible?

Thanks!

**update:**

I tried to use **openURL:** to launch another app which is also mine, and its URL scheme has not been registered in the whitelist of the calling app. And turns out that I can launch another app successfully, while **canOpenURL:** is returning *NO*.

I have no idea whether Apple is ONLY changing canOpenURL, or successfully launching another app is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing seems to be how it should be.

These new limitations are supposed to apply to only canOpenURL and not openURL.

In the earlier iOS beta builds the limitations applied to both and this [radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6159379246088192) was filed. As you tested, this has now apparently been fixed.